# Efficient copy-down using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of jQuery code that, when the user changes the value of a select, it copies the value selected down to other similar selects (same CSS class) that follow the one changed, if they don't have a value already.  Is there a more efficient way to do the following?  It runs a bit sluggishly, at least in IE7.

```
$('.selectclass').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    var baseElem = $(this);
    $('.selectclass:gt(' + $('.selectclass').index(this) + ')').each(function (i) {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).val(baseElem.val());
     } 
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be better optimised:

```
$('input.selectclass').change(function(){
    if (this.value !== '') {
        var newVal = this.value,
            boxes = $('input.selectclass');

        boxes.slice(boxes.index(this)).val(function(i, oldVal) {
            return oldVal === '' ? newVal : oldVal;
        });
    }
});
```

NB this is untested. If you could provide an HTML sample (e.g. jsfiddle) it could be tested more easily...

The efficiencies made here:

- using `input.selectclass` should be faster than `.selectclass`, particularly in Internet Explorer
- caching the selector rather than re-using it
- using `this.value` rather than creating a new jQuery instance
- using the inbuilt callback signature of `val` rather than doing the looping manually with `each`.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are all the same class, do you need a foreach?

```
$('.selectclass').change(function() {
$('.selectclass').val($(this).val())
}
```

Comment: The changes are only supposed to affect *subsequent* instances, not all of them on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selectclass').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    $('.selectclass:gt(' + $('.selectclass').index(this) + ')').not(':empty').val($(this).val())
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will investigate tomorrow when I'm back at work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to match the next sibling `<select>` elements down the tree:

```
$(".selectclass").change(function() {
    var origin = $(this);
    var value = origin.val();
    if (value !== "") {
        origin.nextAll(".selectclass").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.val() === "") {
                $this.val(value);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will investigate tomorrow when I'm back at work.